# Searching characters with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

How do I search a string that can have a "<=", ">=" or a "="?

I´ve reached this point:

```
[<>][=]
```

so it searches the first two

Is there any character that inside the [<>] searches "nothing" so i will just get the [=] that follows?

Comment: Just use `?` quantifier: `[<>]?[=]`

Comment: what's wrong for searching only if string contains `=`?

Answer (score 1):

To make some pattern optional, one or zero occurrences, use `?` quantifier:

```
[<>]?=
```

In Java, you can use it with `matches()` to check if a string contains `<=`, `>=` or just `=`:

```
if (s.matches("(?s).*[<>]?=.*")) {...}
```

Or using  a `Matcher#find()` ([demo](http://ideone.com/hdiMpu)):

```
String s = "Some = equal sign";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[<>]?=");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Found " + matcher.group()); 
} // => Found =
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @stribizhev's suggestion to use `?` is to explicitly enumerate the three cases:

```
(<=|>=|=)
```